# Iterate through two TreeMaps to compare in Java

Tags: java, comparison, treemap

At first I had something like this:

```
public static boolean equals(TreeMap<?, Boolean> a, TreeMap<?, Boolean> b) {
    boolean isEqual = false;
    int count = 0;
    if (a.size() == b.size()) {
        for (boolean value1 : a.values()) {
            for (boolean value2 : b.values()) {
                if (value2 == value1) {
                    count++;
                    isEqual = true;
                    continue;
                } else {
                    isEqual = false;
                    return isEqual;
                }
            }
        }
        if (count == a.size()) {
            return true;
        }
    }
}
```

Then found that nope it didn't work. I'm checking to see if every element in Object a is the same as in Object b without using Iterate or Collection. and in the same place... any suggestions? Would implementing a for-each loop over the keySet() work?

So, something along these lines? Needing to take in account **BOTH** keys and values: (Not an answer - test code for suggestions)

Comment: are `a` and `b` `TreeMap`s as the title suggests? If so, why compare them as `Object` references?

Comment: Yes, they are treemaps, that was my bad when changing the name of them, that's not the issue at the moment. Sorry for that! - Fixed it.

Comment: It seems the AbstractMaps' default implementation fits: http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/AbstractMap.html#equals(java.lang.Object)

Comment: Since you're comparing the values of two Maps in iteration order, you could do that directly by converting them both to Lists and comparing those: `new ArrayList(a.values()).equals(new ArrayList(b.values()))`. If both the keys and the values must match then it's even simpler: `a.equals(b)`.

Comment: How would this account for them if they need to match up with the keys?

Comment: If you just need to compare the keys of both maps, a.keySet().equals(b.keySet()) is sufficient.

Answer (score 4):

This should work as `values()` are backed up by the `TreeMap`, so are sorted according to the key values.

```
List<Boolean> aList = new ArrayList<>(a.values());
List<Boolean> bList = new ArrayList<>(b.values());

boolean equal = aList.equals(bList);
```

This should be a bit faster than a `HashSet` version.

And this won't work as @AdrianPronk noticed:

```
a.values().equals(b.values())
```

Comment: `TreeMap.values()` returns a `Collection`. There is no requirement for `Collection.equals()` to work in this way.  Only the `equals()` methods of `Set` and `List` check the contents for equality.

Comment: why does .values() ask me to create a method for it? isn't it already there when you import the class?

Comment: It might be that `a` in your case is some other than a `Map` class. Or you casted it to some other interface?

Answer (score 3):

How about this :

```
Set values1 = new HashSet(map1.values());
Set values2 = new HashSet(map2.values()); 
boolean equal = values1.equals(value2);
```

Answer (score 1):

For Comparing two Map Objects in java, you can add the keys of a map to list and with those 2 lists you can use the methods retainAll() and removeAll() and add them to another common keys list and different keys list.

The correct way to compare maps is to:

1. Check that the maps are the same size(!)
2. Get the set of keys from one map
3. For each key from that set you retrieved, check that the value retrieved from each map for that key is the same

Comment: Good answer. Well Done.